# "method" method in Crockford's book: Javascript: The Good Parts

Tags: javascript, methods

Douglas Crockford wrote in his book (Page 4):

Throughout the book, a `method` method is used to define new methods, This is its definition:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

Then he starts to use this `method` to add method in `Number, String, Function, Object, Array, RegExp`, and here is the complete list：

P33:

```
Number.method('integer', function () {...});
String.method('trim', function () {...});
```

P40 (not sure if there is a misprint in Page 41: the end () ):

```
String.method('deentityify', function () {...}());
```

P43 & P44:

```
Function.method('curry', function () {...});
```

P47 (I am confused here, don't know why Crockford define `new` method, and he seems never use `new` method in the book):

```
Function.method('new', function () {...});
```

P48:

```
Function.method('inherits', function (Parent) {...});
```

P54:

```
Object.method('superior', function (name) {...});
```

P62:

```
Array.method('reduce', function (f, value) {...});
```

P79:

```
Array.method('pop', function () {...});
Array.method('push', function () {...});
Array.method('shift', function () {...});
```

P82:

```
Array.method('splice', function (start, deleteCount) {...});
```

P84:

```
Function.method('bind', function (that) {...});
```

P88:

```
RegExp.method('test', function (string) {...});
String.method('charAt', function (pos) {...});
```

P90 (not sure if there is a misprint in Page 91: the end () ):

```
String.method('entityify', function () {...}());
```

**The definition `method` is based on `Function`, why it can be used in `Number, String, Object, Array, RegExp` besides `Function`?** And can this `method` be used to other data type?

Another small question: in Page 63 & 64, the definition of `Array.dim, Array.matrix, Array.identity` didn't use above `method`, why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All native functions in JavaScript inherit from `Function.prototype`. `Number`, `String`, `Object`, `Array` and `RegExp` are all functions, therefore they inherit from `Function.prototype`.

`method` is intended to be called on constructor functions. Its job is to make the function you supply to it into a method that exists for every object created by the constructor function on which you called `method`. You will notice that in the functions that Crockford passes to `method`, he makes use of `this`, which is a reference to the object on which the method was called. `Array.dim`, `Array.matrix` and `Array.identity` make no use of `this` because they operate independently of any particular array and hence do not need to be methods of individual array objects. They are assigned as properties of the `Array` function for convenience: they could equally well exist on their own as functions in the global scope.

Comment: I am not sure if Number, String, Object, Array, RegExp (Maybe Function and Date and Boolean as well) are all functions. It seems they are Global Objects.

Comment: @John: I assure you, they are all functions. Try `alert(typeof Number)` etc. if you don't believe me, or check the specification (section 15.1.4): http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm. They are also properties of the global object, if that's what you were getting at.

Comment: @John: I see, you've looked at Mozilla's documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects. It's correct in that as well as being functions, `Number`, `String`, `Object` et al are also objects, because all functions are objects; it's also true that as properties of the global object, they're available globally so could be described as "global objects". However, in light of the existence of the officially defined term "global object", I find Mozilla's use of the term "Global Objects" rather unhelpful.

Comment: Thank you! You even know the reason why I have the question. I cannot understand Mozilla's term "Global Objects" very well, maybe this is my next question in SO.

Comment: so why cant I run these in node 5.2.0? I get a String.method is not a function error

Comment: @ManuelHernandez: It isn't a standard method. It's an example from Douglas Crockford's book.

Comment: When I assigned Crockford's function to `Function.prototype.method` in a Chrome browser console it works as expected. `Number.method` is defined. When I tried it in NodeJS, `Number.method` is `undefined`. It's what led me to this question after I tried this out while reading Crockford's book.

Answer (score 4):

As an aside, on P40:

The end () means "use the function that this function returns", not the outer function that returns it.

If he had left off the final (), a call to deentityify would return a function, rather than a string.

In Douglas Crockford's own words:

> We immediately invoke the function we just made
>   with the () operator. That invocation creates and returns the function
>   that becomes the deentityify method.

Answer (score 3):

The solution as given by @Tim Down is accurate, but not completely clear.

> **Function object vs Function instance object**

First of all, in javascript, a function is also an object. From this, I mean not the object created by new () construct, but the function itself. To avoid confusion, I would refer such objects as  **Function object**, and for object created using new () construct of a function as **Function instance object**.

> **_ proto _ and prototype properties**

Any *function object* in javascript has two properties:  **_ proto _**  and **prototype**. Moreover, any *Function instance object* (created using new constructor) has a property  **_ proto _** . The  **_ proto _**  is what defines the inheritance. Some good resource on this could be found at

http://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

> **How is inheritance defined?**

An object objA inherits another object objC if objA and objC are connected through any number of **_ proto _** . So if objA has  **_ proto _**  equal to objB, and objB has **_ proto _**  equal to objC, then objA inherits objB and objC, while objB inherits objC.

> **What is meant by inheritance?**

It means any inheriting object can *use* any property of inherited object.

> **What is Function.prototype**

It is the object whom **_ proto _**  of every *function object* refers. This means every *Function object*  has access to properties of Function.prototype, since every  *Function object*  inherits Function.prototype object. This also means that if  *method* property is added to Function.prototype object, it would be available to all the possible *Function objects* in javascript. This includes Strings, Number, etc.

> *this.prototype[name] = func;*

this refers to  *Function object*  when the 'method' is invoked from *Function object*s like Number, String, etc. Which means that we now have a new property in *Function object* with name "name", and its a function 'func'.

> **What good is *prototype* property of *Function object***

A *function object*'s **prototype** is referred to by the *Function instance object*'s  **_ proto _** created using that function's new construct.

If the following was executed:

> Number.method('integer', function () {...});

then Number.prototype has that **integer** method defined in it. This means each Number *function instance object*, e.g. new Number (2.4), would "inherit" this new property 'integer' from Number.prototype, since that Number *function instance object* would have its  **_ proto _**  set to Number.prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this prototype method:

```
String.prototype.deentityify = function () { ... }
```

Then:

```
document.writeln('&lt;&quot;&gt;'.deentityify( ));
```

We can see:
`<">`

Answer (score 0):

Example: Currying can be rewritten as follows, if anyone got stuck. See [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ee86o5d7/)

```
 Function.prototype.curry = function ( ) {
 var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
 var args = slice.apply(arguments);
 var that = this; 
 return function () {  
    return that.apply(null,args.concat (slice.apply(arguments)));
 }
};
var add = function(a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}
var add1 = add.curry(1);
document.writeln(add1(6)); // 7
```