# TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'method'

Tags: javascript

Going through the example code for chapter 5.4 in Javascript: The Good Parts, the following is used to demonstrate the use of the functional pattern to call super methods:

```
Object.method('superior', function (name) {
    var that = this, method = that[name];
    return function () {
        return method.apply(that, arguments);
    };
});
```

This would be used as follows (where "cat" is another constructor function that has a 'get_name' function defined) :

```
var coolcat = function (spec) {
    var that = cat(spec),
        super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
    that.get_name = function (n) {
        return 'like ' + super_get_name(  ) + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};
```

However when running the sample code, F12 tools show the following:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'method'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["method" method in Crockford's book: Javascript: The Good Parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966936/method-method-in-crockfords-book-javascript-the-good-parts)

Comment: Did you forget to add `Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};` from the book?

Answer (score 4):

Douglas Crockford uses the following (defined on page 4 of the book)

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the method `method` is not defined in your code, check the book for a place where the author defined the method `method`.

Apparently @Andreas has found the method, and now I remember it.

The method `method` is used so that when it is called on any object, it defines a method on that object where the name of that method is the `name` parameter passed to `method`, and the implementation of that method is the `func` function parameter.

You need to include this in your console for things to work correctly.