# JavaScript method named 'method': where is it defined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, properties

Section 6.6. of the book 'JavaScript: The Good Parts', calls
a method of Array as follows. Where in the prototypical inheritance
hierarchy of JavaScript objects is the 'method' method defined. I
have searched the [annotated ECMAScript 5.1 reference](http://es5.github.io/) on the
[Mozilla Developer Network JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) but could not find it.

```
Array.method('reduce', function (f, value) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
        value = f(this[i], value);
    }
    return value;
});
```

If anyone could tell me where this method is coming from I would
greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine it's a custom method implemented to take a function name and implementation. If the native function doesn't exist, it'll implement the polyfill for you. Only an educated guess though...

Comment: Crockford is not the best place to go to for "classical inheritance" he never does it right. Creates an instance of Parent to set prototype of Child and claimed Patent constructor can't be re used. He's worried about encapsulation and needs private members but breaks it when changing objects he doesn't own. More on prototype in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: Even if you don't like constructor functions then the following eBook has better examples. I suggest reading the answer in the other comment first so you understand instance specific and prototype members and know the role a constructor plays. Then this one: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crockford adds that method to Function.prototype as a helper (like benhowdle89 suggested):

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

["method" method in Crockford's book: Javascript: The Good Parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966936/method-method-in-crockfords-book-javascript-the-good-parts)