# Adding Methods to array prototype so i can apply it to array object.But it is giving an error TypeError: Array.method is not a function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying add a method to Array prototype.But it is giving me an error **TypeError: Array.method is not a function**

I am trying this example from JavaScript: The Good Parts.

Here is a piece of my code.

```
    Array.method('reduce',function(f,value){
      var i;
      for(i=0; i < this.length; i+1){
        value = f(this[i],value);
      }
      return value;
    });


    var data = [1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    var add = function(value1, value2){
      return value1 + value2;
    }

    var result = data.reduce(add, 0);

    console.log(result);
```

I want to apply the **reduce** method to **data** array. So i can do addition ,multiplication on array and return the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the code you have tried is correct. I think you are trying to add all the elements and return using reduce function to array. But to achieve what you wanted,checkout fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/x2ydm091/2/

```
Array.prototype.reduce=function(f, value){
    for(var i=0;i< this.length;i++){
        value=f(this[i],value);
    }
    return value;
};

var add = function(a,b){
    return a+b;
}

var data = [1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var result = data.reduce(add,0);
alert(result);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it is working. But i am still confused with why Array.method() is not working as douglas crockford used this example to explain augmenting Array.prototype.

Comment: Array.method doesn't exist and didn't.

Comment: @AbhiDhadve This link will clear your doubts.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966936/method-method-in-crockfords-book-javascript-the-good-parts . Also if mine answer helped you, accept it as answer.. ;)

Comment: Here is the actual solution that @Rakesh_Kumar provided. First we have to add it to Function.prototype .    Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

Answer (score -1):

I am reading the book as well and I I think this does not work because before in the book he defined a method called `method` to avoid the use of `Array.prototype.something`, or `Function.prototype something` everytime you want to add methods to array, function or objects prototypes.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
this.prototype[name] = func;
return this;
};
```

Append the above code at the beginning. I had the same problem. They have mentioned this in Preface. Check it out.... I hope it helps.... :)